# How to make element disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

When I'm disabling a

```
 <form:input type="text" path="lateTimeValue" disabled="true" id="lateTime" />
```

element, but it passes its value to the server.

What do I need to do to make it not pass its value to the server on submit?

Comment: make the value="" before submitting.

Comment: A disabled element should not pass its value in a request. Are you sure it's been disabled?

Comment: Are you serializing the form with jquery or javascript??

Answer (score 0):

you can use `readonly` property:

```
<input type="text" path="lateTimeValue" id="lateTime" readonly />
```

this should not be submitted in any browser because it is readonly.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have tagged this question in jQuery and Javascript. So if you are serializing the form with jQuery then use :

```
$('form').find('input,select,textarea,button').not(':disabled').serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using disabled attribute , example

```
<input type="text" path="lateTimeValue" disabled id="lateTime" />
```